# Python module: how to prevent importing modules called by the new module

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import, python-module

I am new in `Python` and I am creating a module to re-use some code.
My module (`impy.py`) looks like this (it has one function so far)...

```
import numpy as np
def read_image(fname):
    ....
```

and it is stored in the following directory:

```
custom_modules/
              __init.py__
              impy.py
```

As you can see it uses the module numpy. The problem is that when I import it from another script, like this...

```
import custom_modules.impy as im
```

and I type `im.` I get the option of calling not only the function `read_image()` but also the module `np`.

**How can I do to make it only available the functions I am writing in my module and not the modules that my module is calling (numpy in this case)?**

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: It seems to me that this is pretty normal, as `import` makes a module belong to a module's memory space. So, what do you mean by "I get the option of calling (...)"? Is that a proposition of your IDE? In this case,

Comment: @Joël Yes, it is a proposition of the IDE (Spyder). But in any case I think that it is not good that the user is able to call numpy through my module and it should be a way of preventing that...

Comment: Well, I would say that this a problem of the IDE, not of Python, that provides you references to all object available.

Comment: I don't think is that...I think it should be a way of preventing that to happen...

Comment: Right, I see that in Idle, so I understand your concern of things being a bit confusing between module imports and module attributes/class/functions, see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I've got a proposition, that could maybe answer the following concern: "I do not want to mess class/module attributes with class/module imports". Because, Idle also proposes access to imported modules within a class or module.

This simply consists in taking the conventional name that coders normally don't want to access and IDE not to propose: name starting with underscore. This is also known as "weak « internal use » indicator", as described in [PEP 8 / Naming styles](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles).

```
class C(object):
    import numpy as _np  # <-- here
    def __init__(self):
        # whatever we need
    def do(self, arg):
        # something useful
```

Now, in Idle, auto-completion will only propose `do` function; imported module is not proposed.

By the way, you should change the title of your question: you do not want to avoid imports of your imported modules (that would make them unusable), so it should rather be "how to prevent IDE to show imported modules of an imported module" or something similar.

Comment: I agree with your last statement, the question title should be updated

Answer (score 1):

You could import numpy inside your function

```
def read_image(fname):
    import numpy as np
    ....
```

making it locally available to the `read_image` code, but not globally available.

Warning though, this might cause a performance hit (as `numpy` would be imported each time the code is run rather than just once on the initial import) - especially if you run `read_image` multiple times.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. I have to run that function many times and, also, it is called by other functions...that's why I wanted to have another solution...Thanks!

Comment: The import will only be done the first time, whether it's lazy or not. Importing a module that's already in sys.modules only binds the name, it doesn't run the code in the module again.

Comment: If `numpy` is needed by the only function available in the module, there is no interest to hide the import inside a function as the import will be done anyway. Worse, if the function is to be called multiple times, the check for import, even if not costly, will be made multiple times.

Comment: @betelgeuse To provide a more complete answer, it might be useful to know *why* having numpy around is such a problem...

Comment: @danodonovan because I don't what to see that in the options the IDE gives me when I am calling a function of that module

Comment: That seems to be the real question.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to hide it, then I suggest creating a new directory such that your structure looks like this:

```
custom_modules/
    __init__.py
    impy/
        __init__.py
        impy.py
```

and let the new `impy/__init__.py` contain

```
from impy import read_image
```

This way, you can control what ends up in the `custom_modules.impy` namespace.